# IR remote receiver not working while relay is HIGH

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm newbie with Arduino, I have just one week of research.

I brought I starter kit and done the example projects. Now I'm trying to create one on my own. But I'm having troubles:

I could manage to make a example of controlling a LED using IR remote. But, when I changed the LED to a relay and a motor (using 5V pin of the Arduino board, i. e., without external supply), I can't turn off the relay using the remote (using communication through the serial port - USB - it works).

I start my Arduino.ino with the relay LOW and I can turn it HIGH using IR remote, and so turning the motor on. But after that the IR receiver doesn't receive data anymore (I call resume method properly).

The problem is not in the code, because the same code works with LED example (to turn it on and turn it off). I'm suspecting that relay + motor is expanding the total of energy when it's on, but I cannot prove it.

Please help-me.

Suggestion of apps to draw the Arduino Electric Scheme will be appreciated too.

Thank you.

Comment: Please attach the sketch you made, because sometimes a problem in the FW can make strange things with different HW.
As for your problem, it's really dangerous to power inductive loads directly from an IC. because 1) it usually doesn't provide enough power and 2) inductive loads require flyback diodes (search on google for that). So, first of all try to put a transistor and a diode on the output (e.g. use this http://i.stack.imgur.com/VcJCl.gif). Any NPN should work (e.g. BC337 or BC537), as a diode you can use a 1N4007, a resistor between 1 and 10 kOhm shoud work..

Comment: And BTW if your relay/motor is a 5V version use 5V as power supply, not 12V

Comment: Frarugi87, thank you for your answer. I'll try putting diode and transistor to my scheme.

Comment: Frarugi87 I found that my problem was due to supply noise. I did as explained here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101921/supply-noise-due-to-motor and cut wires to small I could and it worked.

Comment: So, I'd like to ask how to avoid or decrease the amount of noise created by a motor. Do you know any component for this?

Comment: First of all you should check if the power supply can give you the required amount of current. Try to use a higher current supply, power the motor and check the current with a multimeter. Then if the current supplied by your supply is enough (at least twice the current you measured), the problem should be the noise. Put a big capacitor across the power rails (it depends on the current, but values around 1000-10000 uF should work) and put a 100nF capacitor on every IC's power pins. Then let us know.
BTW, what is the voltage for the motor? 5V?